# How to detect declared but undefined functions in C++?

Tags: c++, xcode

The following compiles, links and runs just fine (on Xcode 5.1 / clang):

```
#include <iostream>

class C { int foo(); };

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    C c;
    cout << "Hello world!";
}
```

However, `C::foo()` is not defined anywhere, only declared. I don't get any compiler or linker warnings / errors, apparently because `C::foo()` is never referenced anywhere.

Is there any way I can emit a warning that in the *whole program* no definition for C::foo() exists even though it is declared? An error would actually be better.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a static analysis tool would do that, but I wouldn't know. Of course there are complications in that there are multiple possible sources of that definition.

Comment: It was a common practice to define (private) methods without implementation for disallow the copy (in C++03, until = delete)...

Comment: Why do you want to detect them? Just for curiousity?

Comment: @oxfordatnight - So what do you want this to do when you include, say `<cstring>`, and you never call strcpy() or strcmp()?   Or if you have a class that turns off copying and assignment by making these functions unimplemented?

Comment: @Deduplicator: to do proper code clean up  for instance. You want to get rid of a function completely, but you forgot it at one place. Another example if you want to add it all, but acidentally, you only added the declaration. This is a very interesting question to which I have no answer... Other than parsing the code with llvm or some expensive and useful static code analyzer...

Comment: @Deduplicator: remove useless/obsolete code ?

Comment: If you don't mind using a third part tool then [cppclean](https://code.google.com/p/cppclean/) looks like it does what you want. In the list of things it checks it includes `Unnecessary function declarations`.

Comment: I'm sure some of the lint tools out there can do this. But I suspect you'll get a lot of false positives.

Comment: This is the C++ version of the ["If a tree falls in a forest..."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_a_tree_falls_in_a_forest "If a tree falls in a forest, and no one is around to hear it does it make a sound?") question. Barring any static analysis tools, the linker is the only entity that would be interested in detecting this. But since it's only interested in linking definitions with things that *reference* those definitions, it *isn't* interested in detecting it. So someone else needs to be in the forest.

Comment: Gcc option `-Wunused-function` might provide a part. No idea how many false positives due to inlining though.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: "Unnecessary function declarations" might also mean unused functions with definition.

Comment: @Deduplicator: same to you ^ Although, the gcc option might not be portable as opposed to the static analyzer.

Comment: I think detecting all unused (aka useless) code is equal to solving the halting problem, which is why the standard does not try. Instead, it only mandates what must be found.

Comment: @Lilshieste: I am an "entity" interested in this... It is indeed true that the linker does not care because it does not need to link to `C::foo()`, but I recently found such a declared but undefined function in production code... `-Wunused-function` does not detect non-static undefined declarations.

Comment: @Deduplicator: This is not equivalent to the halting problem. For `if ( false ) foo();` would still generate a linker error (which I want) even though `foo()` is never called.

Comment: @oxfordatnight: Well, if you want to remove all never run code, that's what it becomes. Otherwise, it's just hard and few tools can help. (There were some suggestions here)

Comment: @oxfordatnight I understand that you're an "entity" interested in this. :-) I only meant that nothing in the compilation process is interested in it, so you'll need to resort to some kind of third party tool. (This probably doesn't tell you anything you didn't already know; I just wanted to make sure everyone was on the same page about it.)

Answer (score 2):

There are good reasons why it is not easily feasible. A set of header files could declare many functions, some of which are provided by *additional* libraries. You may want to `#include` such headers without using all of these functions (for instance, if you only want to use some `#define`-d constant).

Alternatively, it is legitimate to have some header and to implement (in your library) only a subset of the API defined by the header files.

And a C++ or C header file could also define the interface of code defined by potential plugins, for programs which usually run without plugins. Many programs accepting plugins are declaring the plugin interface in their header file.

If you really wanted to have such a check, you might perhaps consider customizing GCC with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/); however, such a check is non trivial to implement currently (and you'll need link time optimization too).

Comment: That's not an answer, really. Furthermore, lint passes and static analysis tools can usually be configured to only report errors for files within a given list of directories, thus ignoring 3rd party dependencies.

Comment: This is an interesting point. I can see the issue (it would mean I always have to link to libraries whose headers I include). This is problematic for Boost, say. Still - it would be nice to have something to do the check if I wanted to.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps try calling all functions in your implementation map and adding a try catch that spits out some warning if they segfault.

Comment: Segfault is a result of undefined behavior, and try-catch can't catch UB.

Answer (score -1):

**You don't.** Or rather, this is not the job of the compiler

I guess I'm just repeating what other said in the comments, but:

- It's actually a feature (see unimplemented private constructor)
- It wouldn't really really help, as the "bug" here is that no proper code cleanup was done prior to committing the code, and an unimplemented *and* unused function is really you smallest problem then. What about all the other stuff that hasn't been cleaned up? The likelihood of having an *implemented* and unused function seems just as high to me, and it's the same mess more or less.

Rather than worry about this specific case, I would check if this was just a one time glitch, or if your development team could improve some procedures that would prevent such things in the future.

Answer (score -1):

As far as languages such as C++ are concerned, detecting and reporting undefined functions will defeat one of the important feature provided by it. Virtual/pure-virtual functions are one of the important mechanism by which C++ implements run-time polymorphism.

If you are developing a library to be used by its clients, you might have declared-but-not-defined virtual functions. You may leave the definition for its clients. In such cases, if the compiler were to report such undefined functions, it won't be beneficial.