# Is it legal to declare but not define a function that is unused?

Tags: c++, linker, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

Let's say I have have the following files in C++:

```
// bar.hpp
int foo();
int bar();

// bar.cpp
#include "bar.hpp"
int bar() { return 3; }

// main.cpp
#include "bar.hpp"
int main() { return bar(); }
```

Note that `foo()` was declared (in both `main.cpp` and `bar.cpp` translation units) but never defined anywhere. On the other hand, it wasn't used anywhere either. Is this legal? I suspect it's fine in practice because neither compiled unit refers to the `foo` symbol so the linker will never try to find it. But I'm curious about whether the C++ standard guarantees that this is OK. (I'm not even sure that the standard talks about linking.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect declared but undefined functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201873/how-to-detect-declared-but-undefined-functions-in-c)

Comment: Undefined, but declared functions are used in meta programing.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Thanks, that is certainly related, but it doesn't quite answer the question, certainly not from a language-lawyer point of view.

Comment: FWIW, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63908038/4342498) you can see an example of actually using a declared but not defined function in use of extracting a type for generic programming.

Comment: @NathanOliver Great example, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's legal. Functions and variables are required to be defined only when they are [*odr-used*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition). odr-use is a precise way of saying *use* them, which for functions loosely means you call it or take its address.

To be a bit more precise, the function has to appear in a potentially-evaluated expression, which is everything except within

```
decltype
sizeof
typeid
noexcept
```

The standard indeed doesn't talk about linking, it instead only talks about translation units. Even though we usually just call an implementation a "compiler", we really mean the entire toolchain, including the linker. So even though the linker isn't explicitly mentioned, it is very much implied.