# C++ allows instantiation of objects with just function declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, c++20

Simple code below.

```
class Base{
public:
    int fcn();
};

int main() {
   Base b; // clause 1
}
```

Why does this compile? Clause 1 creates a `Base` instance but the function `fcn()` is never defined.

Comment: Your code as is doesn't compile: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88c9b8e865ea36f6

Comment: "of course there is an error. Why is there no error?" ... more seriously, its a linker error you get, the compiler is used to not see all defnitions

Comment: A (complete) C++ program could be made up of many different source files. It is perfectly legal for the *definition* of `fcn()` to be in a different one than its *declaration*.

Comment: Sorry please see my revised one

Comment: now the question is less clear. Why do you expect that code to fail?

Comment: You never used `fcn`, so its non-existence is not a problem.

Comment: Not just C++, but this has been the case with C for over 50 years. Add a function declaration, don't call this function anywhere, don't define this function anywhere. Not problems, whatsoever.

Comment: Object b is created  as shown in clause 1. You can't create object when class has function without definition.  This class is so called incomplete

Comment: "You can't create object when class has function without definition" says who?

Comment: @yapkm01 That's not true.  As long as you never try to use the function there is no need for it in your program.

Comment: Coming from Java background.. that won't be allowed. Just curious

Comment: actually there are many cases where one would declare something but not define it. I just dont remember a simple one from the top of my head

Comment: @yapkm01 Some even use this feature as a design pattern (declaring a class method and never defining it so that the program fails to compile if it is ever called).

Comment: @atru thats a good one :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number right? :) Alexandrescu Modern C++ I think - but I would need to check it and the book is at home :D

Comment: @atru thats where I got my notion of "modern c++" from and I am always baffled when nowadays ppl call just everything "modern" :D

Comment: I know this is not a discussion fitted for a comment, but I'm actually reading this book now and appreciating it a lot :) the generic "modern" is much useful day today!!

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number quick search on google revealed a pile of C++ books.. all Modern.. I see the point :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it legal to declare but not define a function that is unused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63921741/is-it-legal-to-declare-but-not-define-a-function-that-is-unused)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `Base b;` is not a compiler error is because the compiler cannot know in general if a definition is missing.

The code you posted might be the complete translation unit while the definition is in a different translation unit. Only the linker will issue an error when a definition is needed (eg to call the fucntion) but no definition can be found.

---

There are actually many cases where one wants something to be declared but not defined (or only conditionally defined). It follows two examples.

---

Suppose you have a method with a `double` argument and you want to prevent a user to call it with an `int`. Implicit conversions can be annoying, implcicit conversion of fundamental types even more. One can do something like this:

```
struct foo {
    void do_something(double) {}
};
struct bar {
    void do_something(double) {}
    void do_something(int);      // no definition !!
};
    
int main()
{
    foo{}.do_something(1);
    bar{}.do_something(1);
}
```

`foo::do_something(double)` can be called with an `int`. On the other hand `bar::do_something(double)` has to compete with `bar::do_something(int)` in overload resolution and `bar{}.do_something(1);` results in a linker error.

Note that here are nicer ways to get a nicer compiler error message ([`= delete` since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions)). However, the point is: As long as you are only calling `bar::do_something` with a `double` all is fine. No error. And no error to be expected. It works and is completely valid C++.

---

Another example is tag types used to distinguish between different instantiations of a template:

```
struct tag1;   // no definition !!
struct tag2;   // no defniition !!

template <typename T> struct foo;
template <> struct foo<tag1> { /* something */ };
template <> struct foo<tag2> { /* something else */ };

int main() {
    foo<tag1> a;
    foo<tag2> b;
}
```

This is completely fine, because the template does nothing that would require its argument to be a complete type. Using types merely to tag instantiations of a template or to select an overload is a common technique and sometimes all you need for the tag is a declaration.

Addmittetly this is different from your example, because its a whole class definition missing and nowhere an instance of the classes is created. Though I would put it in the same bag of: Useful to have a declaration without definition.

Comment: This is really valuable for the unwanted conversions. May spare a few headaches too!

Comment: @atru *modern* c++ has `= delete;` which is nicer, more explicit and better error message

Comment: In my narrowness I thought that I can use `delete` only for constructors, destructors etc :D And I did. It makes sense, thank you.