# Why assigning a function to a `std::function` cause undefined reference?

Tags: c++, std-function

```cpp
#include <functional>

int foo(size_t);
std::string bar(size_t);

int main() {
  std::function<void(size_t)> f;
  f = foo;
  f = bar;
  return 0;
}
```

In the snippet above, I am trying to assign to a `std::function` two functions `foo` and `bar` which are declared as such. I haven't called the functions yet, so why does this result in a linker error?

```
/tmp/ccQwGxWs.o: In function `main':
functionCompatibleTypes.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `foo(unsigned long)'
functionCompatibleTypes.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `bar[abi:cxx11](unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Perhaps a better question is "why taking the address of an undefined function does **not** raise the error in the link step?" -- both are answered in the answers below. On the other hand, not linking will never raise the error. -- see also: [c++ - Enable error when linking if a function is not implemented - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286223/enable-error-when-linking-if-a-function-is-not-implemented)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a pointer to a function requires the address of the function. The compiler does not know the address of the function, so it inserts a symbolic reference that the linker will try to fix up later.

It's important to remember that linking happens after optimization. So if the optimizer removes all references to a function, then the linker will not complain.

Now you may ask why the compiler does Not optimize out the function pointers?

I suspect the answer to that is that std::function is not simple, it does a bunch of work behind the scenes to support arbitary callable types. This is typically achived by generating caller and manager functions for each type that is assigned to the std::function. Pointers to the caller and manager functions are stored in the std::function and when a caller or manager function is called it is passed a pointer or reference (not sure which, it doesn't really matter) to the std::function. The manager function must be called as part of reassigning and destroying the std::function.

A sufficiently aggressive optimiser could un-pick this, but it's decidedly non-trivial and there is no gaurantee that every optimizer will do so. In order to optimise away the code the compiler must first inline the constructor, assignment operator and destructor calls, then spot that it is safe to replace the calls through a function pointer to the manager function with direct calls, then inline the calls to the manager function, and only then will it become visible to the optimizer that the pointers to foo and bar are never actually used.

EDIT: just tested this with the compilers on godbolt, it seems clang at O2 and above succeeded in optimizing out the references to foo and bar, but gcc did not at any optimization level.

Comment: I was starting to despair reading all those "interesting" answers. Happily at least this one passes muster.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation for the functions is missing thats why no reference can be found.

Try:

```c++
#include <functional>

int foo(size_t){};
std::string bar(size_t){};

int main() {
  std::function<void(size_t)> f;
  f = foo;
  f = bar;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know what the error means. I am asking why does it need an implementation? I haven’t called the function anywhere(as far as I can see I am only assigning a declaration)

Comment: @karshtharyani The definition of the function must exist in order to be pointed to. Even if you don't *call* the value through the pointer, you did assign the function to the pointer, so its address must be taken.

Answer (score 0):

The function is declared without implementation, and the address of the function is not obtained after compilation.If you use a function pointer, the compiler will assume that you are probably going to call the function, so you must provide the implementation